# Can't rename or create more than one custom userscript script in Tampermonkey

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

I am currently trying to create 3 userscripts in Tampermonkey for separate pages. Using the GUI, I can click on "Add a new script", however every time I save after making changes, it re-saves over the top of 'My Fancy New Userscript' and there doesn't seem to be any way of renaming the scripts.

Perhaps I am missing something?:)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The name is set by the `@name` directive.  In Tampermonkey, there can never be more than one script with the same `@name`<sup>1</sup>.

[image: Changing the name]

In fact, you should examine and change, or delete, every one of the default `@` directives with each new script.  Most of that is clutter (most of the time), and it's poor practice to have a script run on every page like `@match http://*/*` specifies.

A good starter template is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @match    http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
```

Where you change the `@name` and `@match`(es) for every script.

This template also uses jQuery from the local disk (which you will want to do for any serious scripting), and is fully compatible with Greasemonkey.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is actually a bit of a bug. Tampermonkey should follow the Greasemonkey model, where it's the `@name` + `@namespace` ***combination*** that has to be unique.